# Yii2 No-refresh Page After Submitting Modal Form

Tags: php, ajax, modal-dialog, refresh, yii2

I have a Create Purchase page. It has a Supplier drop down field where I can Add New Supplier that shows a modal when clicked. In the modal is a form for adding a new supplier. After I create a new supplier and click the submit button, the page will be refreshed.

Here is a screenshot:
[image]

The page is refreshed due to the `redirect` function in my action controller:

```
$model->refresh();
return $this->redirect(['index', 'id' => $session['user_id']]);
```

I know that Ajax can maybe solve this problem but I don't know how to start. How do I get the data from my modal form after clicking the Create button to use it in my Ajax function without going through my controller (just for front end display)?

Comment: The image in my question.

Comment: Are you at work? Maybe the site where the image is uploaded is blocked over there.

Answer (score 5):

Disable Yii client validation by adding following line in ActiveForm options

```
'enableClientValidation'=>false
```

Now add your javascript code on form submission to collect your form data and send it to server. Yii will validate this data and if there are any validation errors, we will send it back

```
$this->registerJs('
    $("#contact-form").submit(function() {
        $(".form-group").removeClass("has-error");      //remove error class
        $(".help-block").html("");                      //remove existing error messages

        var form_data = $("#contact-form").serialize();
        var action_url = $("#contact-form").attr("action");

        $.ajax({
            method: "POST",
            url: action_url,
            data: form_data
        })
        .done(function( data ) {
            console.log(data);
            if(data.success == true)    {       //data saved successfully 

            }   else    {       //validation errors occurred
                $.each(data.error, function(ind, vl) {      //show errors to user
                    $(".field-contactform-"+ind).addClass("has-error");
                    $(".field-contactform-"+ind).find(".help-block").html(vl[0]);
                });
            }

        });
        return false;
    });', \yii\web\View::POS_READY, 'my-ajax-form-submit');
```

Now Made some changes in your controller action

```
public function actionContact()
{
    $model = new ContactForm();
    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
        $success = false;
        $error = [];
        if($model->contact(Yii::$app->params['adminEmail']))    {
            $success = true;
        }   else    {
            $error = $model->getErrors();       //get validation error messages
        }
        header('Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate');
        header('Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT');
        header('Content-type: application/json');
        echo json_encode(['success' => $success, 'error' => $error ]);

        Yii::$app->end();
    } else {
        return $this->render('contact', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }
}
```

And it's done.

Comment: thanks! where do I put `registerJs`? inside my Create Purchase page or in my Create Contact modal?

Comment: after I create a contact and click the Create button, the page redirects to another page (createcontact) with only this written on the page: `{"success":true,"error":[]}` I followed all the instructions but modified `actionContact`. I commented the `if($model->contact(Yii::$app->params['adminEmail']))` block and added `$model->save();
        if($model->save()){
             $success = true;
         }else{
             $error = $model->getErrors();       //get validation error messages
         }
        return json_encode(['success' => $success, 'error' => $error ]);`

Comment: Add registerJs code in your Contact modal, and make sure that jquery is loaded in your contact modal

Comment: If you'r rendering model partially, then add "\app\assets\AppAsset::register($this);" this line in your code to register jquery in it.

Comment: if this was the solution to your question, please mark it as the valid answer